# Infinite digraph

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

Given a digraph $\Gamma$. Let $v\in V(\Gamma)$, then $N^-(v)$ denotes the set of $v$'s incoming vertices.

[image]

Let $\Gamma$ has the following properties:

1. There is exactly one vertex  $a\in V(\Gamma)$ s.t. $N^-(a)=\emptyset$
2. If $u\neq v$, then $N^-(u)\neq N^-(v)$
3. There is a vertex  $b\in V(\Gamma)$ s.t.

\begin{align}
a\in N^-(b)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\forall[u\in N^-(b)]\exists[v \in N^-(b)]:N^-(v)=N^-(u)\cup\{u\}
\end{align}
Can we prove that $|N^-(b)|\geq\aleph_0$?

Comment: If you take a graph $b\to a$, then $N^-(b)=\varnothing$, $N^-(a)\neq N^-(b)$ and $b$ satisfies property 3 vacuously

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti such graph is forbidden since $N^-(a)=\emptyset$

Comment: How so? there's an arrow from $b$ to $a$, so $N^-(a)=\{b\}$ unless I'm misunderstanding your definitions

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti the illustration just shows what $N^-$ means

Comment: Yes and if you have a graph with two nodes, $a$ and $b$ and an arrow from $b$ to $a$, then $N^-(a)=\{b\}$, as per the drawing.

Comment: Anyway my real point is that condition $3$ is not saying anything, since you can pick the vertex $b$ with $N^-(b)=\varnothing$ and it will always satisfy $3$ vacuously. You probably want to exclude the source from $3$.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I think your counter-example does not work because $$N^-(a)\neq \emptyset$$ which is the first restrain

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes.
(after dealing with the degenerate case in the comment)

This is true because $b$ satisfies the properties of a [limit ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal), and therefore its cardinality is at least $\aleph_0$.